# How to get icons in pcmanfm Ubuntu 12.10 with only fluxbox

Tags: icons, pcmanfm, fluxbox

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 via mini-iso, after that I installed xinit, xorg, fluxbox, xterm, pcmanfm , chromium-browser and lxappearance. There is for now one set of icons, in lxappearance I chose the icon set and applied but they don't show up in pcmanfm, there I see only text.

How do I get pcmanfm to show folder icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Forget lxappearance.

Make a text file called .gtkrc-2.0 and put the following line in it:

```
gtk-icon-theme-name = "full icon theme name"
```

(of the theme you want, which has to be located in `/usr/share/icons`)

Save it in `/home/username`, and there will be icons!

For more gfk configuration use the following lines in .gtkrc-2.0:

```
#sets the font
gtk-font-name = "sans 8"

#sets the theme
gtk-theme-name = "Industrial"
```

(provided the gtk engine is installed)

More information  about configuring fluxbox is available in the wiki for [fluxbox](/questions/tagged/fluxbox)
and at:

- http://fluxbox-wiki.org/FAQ_en.html
- https://wiki.debian.org/FluxBox
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fluxbox

Comment: it seems your link is dead

Comment: @ Stephane: It appears the fluxbox wiki does not exist anymore exept for the FAQ, thanks for the tip! I corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Your former line with `gtk-icon-theme-name = "Humanity"` was ok, it gave a good working starting point.