# Fluxbox: No folder icons in Thunar and PCManFM

Tags: icons, directory, thunar, pcmanfm, fluxbox

I have an Ubuntu 12.10 installation and wanted to try out Fluxbox as a lightweight window manager. When I open Thunar it displays no icons for folders. I've made sure I have a `.gtkrc-2.0` in my home directory.

Do you have any ideas what to try out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get icons in pcmanfm ubuntu 12.10 with only fluxbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223399/how-to-get-icons-in-pcmanfm-ubuntu-12-10-with-only-fluxbox)

Comment: @Exeleration-G The duplication of the two questions should logically work in the reverse direction, in other words this question should not logically be the duplicate one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line has to be in your `.gtkrc-2.0` file:

```
gtk-icon-theme-name = "Humanity"
```

You can use any icon-theme-name in `/usr/share/icons`, just replace `Humanity` but keep `" "`.

Make sure there is no `#` before the icon-theme line and put your `.gtkrc` file in `/home/username`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Previously I tried "gnome" and "Tango" without success (although they do exist in /usr/share/icons), but "Humanity" works. That will do. :-)